# How to initialize struct values and output the struct correctly

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linked-list

I'm attempting some homework and not sure where to go from here, or if I'm on the right path to doing this correctly. This program was given to me with the goal of creating a function to create a new node with an array large enough to hold the input "count". From there I assume I'm supposed to output the created node.

I've tried setting up the node multiple ways with different pointers, I'm not sure how to initialize the 'newnode' correctly though. And every time I try to use the input 'count' such as 'newnode->array_length = count;' I get a segmentation fault, I don't understand why though, if count is input into the function, isn't it usable in the scope of it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node* previous;
    struct node* next;
    int array_length;
    int* values;
} node;

//creates a new node with an array large enough to hold `count` values
node* create_node(int count) {
//your code here:
    node* newnode;
    newnode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->array_length = count;
    newnode->values;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->previous=NULL;

    return newnode;
}

void append(node* a, node* b) {
    assert(a);
    assert(b);
    a->next = b;
    b->previous = a;
}

int main() {
    node* a = create_node(10);

    assert(a->array_length == 10);
    assert(a->next == NULL);
    assert(a->previous == NULL);

    node* b = create_node(20);

    assert(b->array_length == 20);
    assert(b->next == NULL);
    assert(b->previous == NULL);

    append(a, b);

    assert(a->next == b);
    assert(b->previous == a);
    assert(a->previous == NULL);
    assert(b->next == NULL);

    for(node* cur = a; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        for(int i = 0; i < cur->array_length; i++) {
            cur->values[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation Errors:

```
problem2.c: In function ‘create_node’:
problem2.c:20:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘size’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     newnode->values = malloc(size(int) * count);
                              ^~~~
problem2.c:20:35: error: expected expression before ‘int’
     newnode->values = malloc(size(int) * count);
                                   ^~~
```

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `newnode->values` in `create_node`.

Comment: Also, since this is C, there's no need to cast the result of malloc

Comment: `size` isn't anything. It should be `sizeof`. You have a compilation error. That's my error in my answer, sorry,

Comment: Ahh I see, no worries. It's compiling and running without any issues now, though supposedly it would print 'ok' if I did everything correctly. I'll play with it some more and see where I can get from here. Thanks! I was definitely having trouble setting up the initialization.

Comment: no problem. You can also upvote in addition to accepting, btw

Comment: I did but apparently it's not public yet because I'm new to stack overflow. Sorry about that, but think it's really going to help me through the rest of my semester!

Comment: The code does not match the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating memory for `values`. It's set by default to whatever memory was there before, which was probably an invalid pointer. This would cause a segfault when you tried to access `values`.

```
//creates a new node with an array large enough to hold `count` values
node* create_node(int count) {
//your code here:
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->array_length = count;
    newnode->values = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);   // malloc memory for values
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->previous = NULL;

    return newnode;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I was getting a segmentation fault earlier before the addition of values when using count, I'll try to apply this to both.

Comment: @DazerC it would help if you could post the errors as well, if my above doesn't work for you.

Comment: Included, though it doesn't seem to like the use of int, says it expected an expression. Would I need to allocate space for array_length to use count as well? It was having segmentation faults from my setting array_length = to count before. I thought calling create_node(10) earlier in the program would have set this for the newnode?